# How do you find a cube to mine into with this smooth terrain?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I want to mine a simple square hole into the ground so it will be easy to place ladders. But with this smooth terrain, I have to constantly reshape and adjust the mine shaft so I can place my ladder.

How do these smooth voxels work?

Comment: The terrain in this game is annoying to work with.  Your best bet it make an extra wide hole, one where you could place at least 3 ladders total horizontally.  Then, continue to dig down to where you want, and only place the ladder in the center portion of the wall going up.  The game is being worked on still, so maybe they will fine tune this somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I usually do it:

1. Surround 1 square below me with wood frames.
2. Start digging just under me
3. Wait till you have diamond shaped hole below you
4. Continue the same direction not moving mouse
5. Eventually you will catch the feeling
6. Stop on Ground Floor
7. Place two ladders or more if you can
8. Jump place wood frame under self. FACE ONE CHOSEN DIRECTION
9. Repeat till end:
10. 9.1) Place ladder in front
11. 9.2) Jump\climb up

You gonna have issues when you will be close to surface, near initial Diamond.
All you need to do is to rotate [counter]clockwise and trying to move forth, you will fit inside eventually